# How many constructors can one class have?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am working on a project where I have a Time class, and multiple constructors. Usually, when coding I will only have one constructor with my default parameters, but the instructions for this program are confusing to me.

- The class should have a default constructor (no parameters), which should initialize the object so that it represents the quantity 0.
- The class should also have a constructor with a single integer parameter, which represents a quantity of seconds -- which should be translated into the appropriate notation for a Time object. Note that this constructor with a single parameter will be a "conversion constructor" that allows automatic type conversions from "int" to "Time". If the parameter is negative, default the Time object to represent 0.
- The class should also have a constructor that takes 4 parameters, representing the days, hours, minutes, and seconds to use for initializing the object. If any of the provided values are negative, default the Time object to represent 0. If any of the provided values are too high (but all non-negative), simplify the object to the appropriate representation.

It seems that it wants me to have 3 constructors, one with no parameters, one with one parameter as a conversion constructor to convert seconds into time, and one with 4 parameters initializing day, hours, minutes, and seconds. However, after doing some research I found out that there shouldn't be more than 2 constructors in the class. Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: I'm note sure where you read that "2 constructor" rule. That might be a general guideline, but a class can definately have more than 2 constructors. Many built-in classes have more than 2 constructors.

Comment: "*However, after doing some research I found out that there shouldn't be more than 2 constructors in the class*" - what research? It's perfectly fine to have more constructors. Have you heard of `std::string` or `std::vector`? They have plenty.

Comment: **"Does this make sense to anyone?"** - Not to me. I can't imagine why your source would sugest that.

Answer (score 5):

> However, after doing some research I found out that there shouldn't be more than 2 constructors in the class.

Don't know where you read that, but it's wrong.

Even plenty of standard types, like `std::string` and `std::vector`, have more than that.

> Does this make sense to anyone?

The assignment does. Your claim doesn't.

> How many constructors can one class have?

As many as you like. Well, as many as your compiler allows you to write, anyway. There must be some practical limit due to physics, but [the standard recommends that this limit be at least 4096](http://eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.28).

Comment: I've seen answers downvoted when the premise of the question is flawed. That was my guess.

Comment: Downvote not mine, but I'd guess that it's because the question isn't really answerable. Doesn't reflect on the answer, but what can you do?

Comment: I didn't downvote, I'm not sure where I read about the 2 constructor thing, but I'm looking at it now and it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @MadPhysicist There is a certain irony about downvoting an _answer_ because the question is _unanswerable_...

Comment: There certainly is. Although I've seen it happen enough times in practice to be desensitized. Not implying that it applies here.

Answer (score 0):

with something like date and time this is ridiculous suggestion , there is clearly a need for at least four, default constructor, copy constructor, a constructor that takes an epoc , and constructor that takes a SQL time string

Comment: An SQL time string? Seems pretty random. Why SQL? Anyway, if you want to provide a deserialiser, I would prefer this to be a free factory function.

Comment: @Lightness I just meant it to represt the persistence layer , eg a database represent date/time in yet another  format ..A timestamp

Comment: (My date/time class actually has zero ctors; it's an aggregate with some free utility & factory functions; YMMV but "a need" is a stretch!)

Comment: It really depends on the domain where it will be used, but in an "Enterprise" application it is very common to take time stamps from  lots of different components and time zones.

Comment: In an "Enterprise" application it is common not to pollute your Date/Time class with a constructor for each of those data sources.

Comment: @HenryV they are all legacy ways of representing time/date data

Comment: They're not legacy either

Comment: @lightness , thank you ..what do you suggest "existing"

Comment: @newbie Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @lightness you objected to my use of the worl "legacy" I was only asking for a more suitable alternative

Comment: I was just thing about a system integrator having to manage "time" data from many disparate sources could have a need for a large amount of constructors

Comment: Okay. Well, again, those should not be constructors. Sounds like you're coupling your modules too tightly.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, how do you integrate multiple systems if your date/time class is not overloaded to cope with all the different formats ?

Comment: @newbie With free factories/utility functions, as I said. Your Date/Time class does not need to know about X, Y, Z arbitrary alternative data source - you just need some glue to take one and produce the other. Your way is very tightly coupled - each module needs to know about each other module. You _cannot possibly_ produce a well-maintainable and well-tested Enterprise product like this. I recommend a book on scalable software design!

Comment: tl;dr don't fall for the "everything must be a member function" myth because it's not true